# Symfony 2.x with FOS-Userbundle: Controll all Sessions

Tags: php, symfony, session, fosuserbundle

I'm wondering about this question because until today I everytime found something for symfony but for this not yet.

I have a Symfony-Application with fos-userbundle. 
What I need is the following: 
As admin, I want to see all running sessions, which user, time of login, time of last action, last action (I think the called url would be great), the ability to kill the session and so on.

Is there an easy way for this I didn't found yet?

Thanks!

Comment: you needs to look at this first http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/pdo_session_storage.html later the workaround should be "easy" ;)